# How to disable Xcode suggestion to change let into _

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings, var, let

When Xcode suggests me to change `var` to `let` - I can understand it.

But when I have over9999 warning just because of the fact that xcode suggests me to change all `let` into `_` - I becomes angry. Where can I disable it?

Comment: if your initialize variable never use, warning and set _ removing your variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to remove this warning. And you should **NOT** do this anyway. It's good to enforce best practices.